# In Firefox, is it possible to save a webpage as a PDF?

Tags: firefox, pdf, export

I'm using Firefox on linux exclusively.

Comment: One thing I like about Safari and OmniWeb on a Mac is that the operating system's built-in Print, Save as PDF actually yields **clickable links in the generated PDF**. The very same option does *not* create clickable links in Firefox though. I don't know how Safari and OmniWeb do it (one would expect a Print to PDF option to *not* know anything about some hidden links, and I certainly had not expected non-Apple software to know the internals of that). But if you like clickable links in the PDF, then that might also have an effect on the Firefox solution you choose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Save web pages as PDF with Firefox 3](http://mozillalinks.org/wp/2007/10/save-web-pages-as-pdf-with-firefox-3/)**

or use the **[Screengrab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1146)** addon.

Comment: Awesome! Here is the link to the PrintPDF extension: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5971

Screengrab is no good though: it grabs pages as images, which is horrendously inefficient.

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`cups-pdf`](http://www.arsgeek.com/2007/05/17/5-steps-to-create-a-pdf-printer-print-to-pdf-in-ubuntu/) to Print the page as a PDF.

Comment: That's a decent solution, but I'd prefer a solution that uses firefox only.

Answer (score 3):

[Something that maybe works for you](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5971)

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is to download [CutePDF](http://www.cutepdf.com/) and ps2pdf driver and use Print option in firefox to print PDF. Or use this [Add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1146).

Comment: Note that the add-on is not supported for new versions of Firefox

Answer (score 2):

### 1. Choice

[image: PDF Icon]  [**PDF Mage**](http://www.pdfmage.org/) addon. Nice work in Firefox 51.0.1 (64-bit).

---

### 2. Demonstration

*(Page may incorrect displayed in Firefox web preview, but if I open saved PDF in Sumatra PDF, I have not bugs)*

- Page, which I need convert to pdf — **https://vk.com/wall245887788?offset=60**, [**archive copy**](http://archive.li/jhov7).
- PDF, generate by PDF Mage — **http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/Kristinita/SashaMiscellaneous/blob/master/pdf/KristinaKivaWall.pdf**.

[image: PDF Mage]

---

### 3. Description

1. Free,
2. Active development in February 2017,
3. Good PDF quality,
4. Easy to use. I need only click the button in web-page, which I need to save.
5. Save all images in page (unfortunately, sometimes I get bugs),
6. Generate text as text, not as image. I can search text in generate page.
7. Save web-pages, which not visible for all users. For example, I can save as PDF web-pages in private social network groups.
8. Save data, which can be seen only by following the steps on the web-page. For example, if I open [**page**](https://vk.com/wall245887788?offset=80), I see:

[image: Hide]

If I click to `Показать полностью...`, I see:

[image: Open]

Use PDF Mage I can save all text on image 2.

9. Save 1 web-page as 1 PDF-page. It does not spoil the page. For example, if I use native [**«Save as PDF» in Chrome**](https://www.labnol.org/software/save-web-page-as-pdf/21153/), I can get result:

[image: Spoil page]

Image it spoiled.

10. Save hyperlinks.